# Php - form validation, inconsistent results

Tags: php, validation

I recently created a PHP form (my first one) and I wanted to have a phone number validation feature. Now, I have written the code. But it works for two or three runs and then stops working all together. I don't get any errors. It simply accepts anything that I type in. The rest of the validations (name and radio button entries) work without a problem. I am checking for a 10-digit number (no special characters). The validation must check the length of the entry and should ensure only numbers are entered.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
if (empty($_POST["mobile"])) {
    $mobileerr = "Mobile number is required";
} else {
    $mobile = test_input($_POST["mobile"]);
    if (preg_match('/[^0-9]{10}/', $mobile)) {
        $mobileerr = "Please enter a valid 10-digit mobile number";
    } else {
        $postmobile = true;
    }
}

function test_input($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: Please check any other javascript error using firebug. If you encounter any java script error while loading your page, it will not work as expected.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have not included any javascript whatsoever. The page contains HTML, CSS and PHP. However, I have noticed that if I remove the code and type it in again, it starts working. This has happened twice until now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about change this code:

```
if (preg_match('/[^0-9]{10}/', $mobile)) {
        $mobileerr = "Please enter a valid 10-digit mobile number";
    }
```

with this one;

```
if(strlen($mobile) != 10 || $mobile != ctype_digit($mobile)) {
$mobilerr = "Please..";
}
```

It will check if user input 10 character long and if it's contains only numbers.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, LetsSeao, this didn't work. I entered a full 10-digit number and it still gave an error asking for a valid entry to be made.

Comment: UPDATE: This worked. I made a small mistake which caused it to fail. Now I have to check if it continues working without failing like earlier. Thank you, LetsSeo!

Comment: I'm happy to be helpful. You can accept my answer if you like :)

Comment: Accepted! I hope it works consistently. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

initilaize

> $postmobile = false;

at beginning and then at end check if it is true of false.

Your modified version of code could be

```
function test_input($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}

$postmobile = false;
if (empty($_POST["mobile"])) {
    $mobileerr = "Mobile number is required";
} else {
    $mobile = test_input($_POST["mobile"]);
    if (preg_match('/[^0-9]{10}/', $mobile)) {
        $mobileerr = "Please enter a valid 10-digit mobile number";
    } else {
        $postmobile = true;
    }
}

if ($postmobile === false) {
    die("Invalid Mobile Number"); //Here you can postback error message and skip further execution.
}
```

Comment: I had already set $postmobile to false. I'm sorry I didn't mention it. But the problem is not with $postmobile. The validation itself is not returning the required result and I'm not able to figure out why.